# Java memory leak when using an array

Tags: java, memory-leaks

wanted to confirm my assumption.  I am looking at code from another developer who was using an array (not linkedhashset/sorted collection etc) and trying to keep it sorted based on insertion but also keeping it of fixed size.  The logic for keeping it of fixed size was to remove the oldest item from the array.  However, when removing the oldest item from the array, the object reference was not nulled out i.e. only the array index was written to with another object.  I think this might let the old (not nulled out) object hang around in memory longer than needed (if not a memory leak altogether) unless I missed anything with scoping.  Any thoughts (I am trying to confirm with a quick test and visualvm as well).  Thanks in advance.

```
public class MemTest {

     private TestBuffer testQuotes = new TestBuffer(10);  //static inner class 


     public static void main(String[] args) {

         System.out.println("Starting!");
         MemTest memTest = new MemTest();
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) { 
             for (int i = 0; i < 2000000000; i++) {
                 memTest.testQuotes.push(1, 12.3);
             }

             try {
                 Thread.sleep(2000);
             }
             catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 System.out.println("exception:" + e);
             }
        }

     }


     private static class QuoteBuffer {
            private Object[] keyArr;  
            private Price[] testArr;  

            public TestBuffer(int size) {
                keyArr = new Object[size];
                testArr = new Price[size];
            }

            public Price get(Object key) {
                if (key != null) {
                    for (int i=0; i<keyArr.length; i++) {
                        if ( key.equals(keyArr[i]) )
                            return quoteArr[i];
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }

            private void _slideTestQuotes() {
                Object prevKey = null;
                Price prevQuote = null;
                Object tempKey;
                Price tempQuote;
                for (int i=0; i<keyArr.length; i++) {
                    // slide key to the next index
                    tempKey = keyArr[i];
                    keyArr[i] = prevKey;
                    prevKey = tempKey;
                   // tempKey = null;  //I am guessing uncommenting this should make a difference

                    // slide quote to the next index
                    tempQuote = quoteArr[i];
                    quoteArr[i] = prevQuote;
                    prevQuote = tempQuote;
                 //   tempQuote=  null;   //I am guessing uncommenting this should make a difference
                }
            }

            public void push(Object key, Double quote) {
                _slideTestQuotes();
                keyArr[0] = key;
                quoteArr[0] = new Price(quote); //quote;
            }
     }






       public class Price {

            Double price;
            Double a1;
            Double a2;
            Double a3;
            Double a4;
            Double a5;
            Double a6;

            Price(Double price) {
                this.price = price;
                this.a1 = price;
                this.a2 = price;;
                this.a3 = price;
                this.a4 = price;
                this.a5 = price;
                this.a6 = price;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Java has a GC. You need to really work hard to get a memory leak, an object doesn't have to be "nullified" in order to be collected, it just need to be unreachable.

Comment: You don't have to null out an Object as long as there are no more references to it. Also keep in mind that `Double` != `double`...

Comment: And what's the problem you have? Are you hitting OutOfMemoryError?

Comment: Welcome to Java where you don't need to manage memory yourself. No you don't need to set the temp variables to null and you will not have memory leak by this code.

Comment: I know Double != double - I just wrote this in a few minutes to test.  I understand the references part (which is why I mentioned the scope in my post).  I think (as per my post) that not nulling the object in the array may cause the object to hang around longer and instead of being collected in the young generation, its being migrated to s0/s1 and then perhaps even to old generation.  The app I ma looking is going through too many old gen collections (I don't have an equivalent test environment to test this plus I cannot make prod changes without making a strong enough case).

Comment: my question - but not my example, was geared towards obsolete references.  I needed to fix my test.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to actually set a reference to null to make it eligible for garbage collection. Consider the following snippet:

```
Double d = new Double(1.1);  // (1)
d = new Double(2.2);         // (2)
```

At line 2 the object handle "d" is assigned a new value. This means the original Double with value 1.1 is now no longer reachable in any way and is eligible for garbage collection. There is no need to specifically write "d = null" first.

Answer (score 1):

The Java garbage collector will collect all objects which are not reachable any longer. You don't have to null out references;

```
ref = null;
ref = newRef;
```

and

```
ref = newRef;
```

have exactly the same effect and, if there are no other references to the object that `ref` was pointing to, will both cause the garbage collector to collect that object.

You only need to null out references when you want to throw away a reference to an object but do not assign a new value to the reference. In that case forgetting to null out the reference might indeed cause a memory leak, because there is still a reference to an object that you might not need anymore.

Answer (score 0):

**However, when removing the oldest item from the array, the object reference was not nulled out i.e. only the array index was written to with another object.** - This is the key point. It doesn't matter whether you are setting the reference to null or setting it to some other object, the "original" object becomes unreachable if there are no more references to it.

Example :

```
arr[0] = new myObject();
MyObject my = arr[0];
arr[0]=null; // or arr[0] = new myObject(); makes no difference. Since The original MyObject is still reachable, it will not be considered for GC.

my=null; // or my=new MyObject() // now the original MyObject instance will be unreachable and hence ready for GC.
```